# "Out" after "to be": adverb, not adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

"Out" is listed as an adverb in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out) in the following example.

> I came around to see you this morning, but you were out.

Does anyone know why it isn't an adjective?

Comment: The question is based on incorrect parsing.

Comment: @Kris I think the question has merit on some level. For example, *why* are these locations following to be considered to be modifying the verb and not adjectival. I think you *could* make a case that when following *to be* it serves as both but we've decided by convention it's still an adverb.  What if we're saying someone is *out of the closet* or *out and about*. These blur the lines a bit as they're a bit more descriptive of the person rather than their state.  This actually might make a decent question when I get in the mood.

Comment: Locative expressions are not predicative, so it can't be an adjective. I take "out" to be a preposition, in accordance with the latest thinking, See here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/out)

Comment: @ Bill J .I agree with you. Each  grammarian  differs  with the  other  grammarian.So  I  think  the  discussion  on  parts  of  speech  tend  be  misleading  and  go  anyway.so I  think  we  give  more importance to meaning than splitting  our  hairs  on this issue

Answer (score 3):

Though  out  is  used  predicatively, it  acts  as  an  adverb  in  the sentence.

> **I came  around  to  see you, but you  were  out.**

We  can not  say  whether  a  word  is  an  adjective or  adverb unless  we know  its  function.

An adjective modifies  a noun or  pronoun  but  an adverb  modifies an adjective, another adverb or  a  whole  sentence.

You were  out means  you went  out. here  out  modifies  the  verb  were  but  not  you.because  there was  some  movement or something  was  not  there( it  was  away)

Here is  a  link  which  helps  you.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out_1

**If  the  lights are  out**  Here out  means  not  shining  which  modifies  lights  so  it is treated  as  an  adjective.

**If the  flowers  are  out.**  here out  means  blossed  which  modifies  flowers  so  it  is  treated  as  an  adjective

Here there  was  no movement of lights  are   flowers but  there  was a change  in their  state.

However , it is really  confusing.It  can  not only  be  an adjective  but also  a  preposition  too.

Here is  a link  which  shows  how  out  can  be  a  preposition  too.

https://simple.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/out

Comment: See also, my comment at OP.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it seems confusing.  *Out* seems like it would be an adjective to describe you.  But, it is in fact a [**place adverb** or **spatial adverb**](https://www.thoughtco.com/adverb-of-place-1691512).

It describes *where the action took place*.  In this case, the confusion is being caused by the fact that your verb is *to be* (past-tense *were*).  We're conditioned to believe that things that follow that verb are adjectives.  But, in this case, what's following it is an adverb of place.

If you substituted another verb the usage becomes clearer:

> I came around to see you this morning, but you jumped out.

This works for adverbial phrases, too.

> I came around to see you this morning, but you were *out in the yard*.

Comment: You could also replace it with *there*, which is clearly an adverb; this strongly suggests adverbiality.

Comment: @Cerberus that was my original example. But I decided that it took the same understanding of adverbial usage as out did ... So I changed it as above ....